# Reply to anyone who sent a DM

Tags: discord, discord.js

**EDIT:** Another question with better answers: [How to reply to any DMs sent to the bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614795/how-to-reply-to-any-dms-sent-to-the-bot)

Is it possible to reply to someone who sent a message to my Discord.js bot?

For example, when someone sends `hi` to my bot's DMs, the bot should reply `Please use !help for the commands' list.`

I've tried a lot of attempts to use the `MessageCollector` but I failed doing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just tell the bot to do that with `client.on('message')`.
Try this:

```
client.on('msg', () => {
  if (msg.channel.type == 'dm' && msg.content.toLowerCase() == 'hi')
    msg.channel.send('Please use !help for the commands' list.')
})
```

This is just a quick example, but you can also add checking for commands and all the other stuff that you do on normal guild channels. To check if the message comes from a [DMChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel) is to check [`Channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type)