# How to reply to any DMs sent to the bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot replying to any DM sent to it.

So I currently have this:

```
client.on('msg', () => {
  if (msg.channel.DMChannel) {
    msg.reply("You are DMing me now!");
  }
});
```

But unfortunately, it does not reply to any DM.

I've tried to replace `msg.channel.DMChannel` with `msg.channel.type == 'dm'` but this didn't work.

I also tried to replace `msg.reply` with `msg.author.send` and `msg.channel.send` but they all didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to pass the msg object to the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) I don't see mentioned the event `client.on('msg')` only [`client.on('message')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message).
With that out of the way:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
    msg.author.send("You are DMing me now!");
    return;
  }
});
```

Just tried this and worked without any issues.

Comment: Ah, this is correct. I didn't even check that when making my answer. Editing mine to reflect the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't receiving the proper 'msg' object, try this:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
        message.reply("You are DMing me now!");
    }
});
```

Edit: I referenced sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3) to come to this conclusion. Maybe this link will help you in the future. Good luck!

Comment: EDIT: It was my mistake xD - It works now!
Thank you very much!

Comment: @André - Yes I've replaced it with the one in your answer `message.channel.type == "dm"` and it is working. I'd recommend @Christian Scillitoe to edit the answer with the correct syntax.